# Google Translate webpage into Serbian Latin

Tags: google-translate

Serbian language has 2 alphabets, Latin and Cyrillic.

When using Google Translate https://translate.google.com/ for translation of page link, default alphabet for Serbian is Cyrillic.

Is Latin supported how to get it?

According to this post
https://support.google.com/translate/thread/1836538/google-translate-to-serbian-latin?hl=en
it should work with explicit longer language code.

Instead of just 'sr' there are 'sr-Latn' and 'sr-Cyrl'.

But even with sr-Latn it still translates into the Cyrillic alphabet.

Note: when using some non existing code, like sr-NN then it remains in English, so it does recognises the code but simply ignores the -Latn suffix.

https://www-wikipedia-org.translate.goog/?_x_tr_sl=en&_x_tr_tl=sr-Latn&_x_tr_hl=en&_x_tr_pto=wapp

The question is also posted to google support:
https://support.google.com/translate/thread/179540069?hl=en